# Android shared element transition not working with SearchView

Tags: java, android, transition, searchview, shared-element-transition

I have a `SearchView` sitting on left top corner in one activity and it is on bottom right corner in another.

```
   <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search a product"
        android:transitionName="search">
```

and in the target activity

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Search a product"
    android:transitionName="search" />
```

In first activity I use the following code, the target activity is `SearchableActivity`

```
            View mySearch =  findViewById(R.id.searchView);
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, mySearch, "search");
            intent = new Intent(this, SearchableActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
```

I thought this was going to be simple to implement :) But there is no animation, it just appears in the bottom. I am not sure where is the problem? Any ideas?

Update:
I tried to enable animations manually:

```
// inside your activity (if you did not enable transitions in your theme)
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
// set an enter transition
getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
// set an exit transition
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

plus enabled it in style:

```
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

and also tried with an `ImageView` object but it just doesn't work for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

From [codepath's guide on shared element transitions](https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition): Make sure you have enabled `android:windowContentTransitions` in your `styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: I now tried that and it doesn't work, but it is a good catch, I didnt have this setting before. I also tried to enable the animations in `onCreate()` function of the activity but doesnt' seem to help.